# Why is jquery mobile button displaying as mini?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-button

I am using the following code for a link styled as a button in jquery mobile:

```
<a data-role="button" data-inline="true"  id="A1" href="#UserDialog" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="slideup"></a>
```

however the button displays as if it contained the data-mini="true" attribute. This only happens on this page on my SPA web application. I have no CSS rules or classes that would have any connection to this link that would cause this. I have tried moving the link around the page to see if a div or other parent had a class that was affecting it but to no avail. I have also tried creating the button programatically from a  element however that also did not work.

I am using Tiatems iOS theme for jquery mobile, but this seems to be the only page with this problem.

I am unsure what is causing this and could definitely use some insight on how to fix this

edit: added more code

```
        <h3>Marketing Rep Information</h3>                  

        <p>
            <b>Name:     </b>  <a data-role="button" data-mini="false" data-inline="true" data-bind="text: CreatorName" id="A1" href="#UserDialog" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="slideup"></a>
        </p>

        <div id="usecTablediv"  data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-inset="true">
            <h2>USECs</h2>
                        <table id="usecTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive">
                          <thead>
                            <tr>                                  
                              <th>Title</th>
                              <th>USEC</th>
                              <th>Rate</th>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>
                             <!-- ko foreach: USECs -->
                             <tr>
                              <td data-bind="text: Title"></td>
                              <td data-bind="text: UsecCode"></td>
                              <td data-bind="text: Rate"></td>
                             </tr>
                              <!-- /ko -->
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
             </div>
        <a id="Signout2"  class="signout" >Sign Out</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting **data-inline="false"** and you should see your button expand to the width you're looking for.

Comment: No joy, also inline shouldnt effect the width

Comment: inline does affect the width, see [JQM Buttons > Inline](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/buttons) ... could you provide a jsfiddle... changing data-inline from true to false should make an immediate change, unless you've got css that we can't see saying otherwise

Comment: sorry meant height, height of the button is the problem, not the width. My mistake

Comment: the problem is that the button is displaying as if it had data-mini="true" which is does not, meaning the button height is only as high as the text, I need it to look like a regular jqm button

Comment: then try adding **data-mini="false"** and see if that changes anything...or have you somehow removed/changed the button's padding, **.ui-btn-inner**... otherwise it's a little difficult to troubleshoot without knowing/seeing any code/style

Comment: dang, still no joy. There is no other html that is effecting that element.